# getting input from click event in javascript and sending it to django or saving it as text file

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x

I have an html file that's a dataframe class.  I added click event to each row.  I want to send fName, lName, Address, Zip to django views.py to do some internal querying.  I am under the impression that I need to use ajax for this.  I'm new to javascript and Ajax and have no idea how to incorporate this into the code.  Any help would be appreciated.  If there is a way for me to save these variables to a txt file, then i can call another function within Django and do it that way.  Not sure, if saving it to text file is the right way to do this.

```
#sample HTML file

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead>
  <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th>first</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>zip</th>
    <th>State</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>mary</td>
    <td>poppins</td>
  <td>3345 leanie rd</td>
  <td>28277</td>
  <td>PA</td>
<tr>
   <td>honas</td>
   <td>bond</td>
   <td>1123 cavalry st</td>
   <td>38788</td>
   <td>GA</td>

function addRowHandlers(tableId) {
if(document.getElementById(tableId)!=null){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var fname = '';
    var lname = '';
    var address = '';
    var zip = '';
    var State = '';
    for ( var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

        rows[i].i = i;
        rows[i].onclick = function() {

            fname = table.rows[this.i].cells[0].innerHTML;                
            lname = table.rows[this.i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            address = table.rows[this.i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            zip = table.rows[this.i].cells[3].innerHTML;
            state = table.rows[this.i].cells[4].innerHTML;
            alert(fname +' ' + lname + ' ' + address +' '+ zip +' '+ state + ' ');
            };
        }
     }
}
</script>
#views.py
def query_result(request):
fname = request.GET(//what do I type here?//)
```

Comment: You don't write anything there, because you're not sending anything from your Javascript to the backend. You need some kind of Ajax function that sends data in the onclick handler.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply.  Is Ajax the only way to accomplish this?  Im new to this whole webserver development.  Thank you

Comment: Ajax just means sending requests via Javascript, so I don't know what else you would want to do. If you want Javascript to make a request when you click something and do something with the response, you need Ajax.

Comment: well i want the user to click on the row.  and use that row as input back into django where I can query the database.  So i guess ajax is the way to go

Comment: Otherwise you could just make the row a link, and not use Javascript at all.

Comment: can you suggest a way to do that?  im new to this whole html and javascript thing and I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, anyway you can help in sending the values to django via Ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165914/discussion-between-rajn-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution is to make Ajax request on click of row and handle the response... The other thing you can try is, load all table related data into javascript Object/Array in python. On row click get respective row data from that javascript object. The problem with this approach is that you will load all table data at once.

Comment: @ omui can you tell me how to make ajax request on click?

Comment: Hi @omui, thanks for your help.  A question.  Under '#ajax' url, what do i pass into that?  Under django, my url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/.  do i pass this as parameter?  Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is Ajax url. which will return the row data.

Comment: @ omui so i ran your code.  but i dont see anything happening when i enter that url

Comment: so in my django.  my url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-form.  When I enter the names lets say "first name, last name, address, zip and state", it takes me to a different url which i created called "search-result" which returns a dataframe of possible names.  On that website do i store the results in search-results.html.  do i put this url into ajax url?

Comment: It should work. Are you using localhost or jsfiddle url? This Ajax request is GET request. I hope you are handling that in python. If you are using chrome, you can check the Ajax request in network tab of chrome debug tool.

Comment: initially i went to jsfiddle and just clicked run and clicked on the table row.  was just curious where the results were stored.

Comment: is there anyway we can carry this conversation to a chat room?  I highly appreciate your help

Comment: Yah, sure we can continue there.

Comment: hmm im not sure how to start a conversation with you.  i tried to go to your profile but dont see that option listed.  anyway you can start one with me?

Comment: Do you use skype, gtalk? or any other IM. I can ping you there. Share you details here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use p5.js library it has a method called httpPost(). It sends JSON data of your selected elements to your backend. Quite easy to use no ajax as well.

Comment: I can't use p5.js as i am getting an download error

Comment: are you downloading it from the official website? You shouldnt be getting any download errors to be honest. Just use the minified version as well.